# "False - True" in Python

Tags: python

The following function is used in the openAI gym Blackjack environment (see https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/blackjack.py)

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

If the function is called indirectly via an `import gym` and loading the blackjack environment via

```
env = gym.make('Blackjack-v0')
```

there is an unwanted behavior. The function is used in the Blackjack class 
e.g. like this:

```
cmp(11, 19)
```

Now the return value is `True`, which is obvious wrong. The wanted result is -1

That's strange and maybe do to some optimizations? Can you explain why?

P.S.: Due to the bug, the player (agend) wins always a Blackjack Game if he "stays".

P.S.: Casting into a float is in gym much more appropriate, because the data type should be float. In this case it works.

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return float(a > b) - float(a < b)
```

Comment: "If the function is called indirectly via an import gym" what does that mean? How is `cmp(11, 19)` indirect?

Comment: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/__init__.py does not contain any calls to `cmp` - what exactly are you talking about related to `import gym` plz?

Comment: env = gym.make('Blackjack-v0')

Comment: then it's most likely a side effect of your `make` implementation which has probably nothing to do with the code of `cmp` you posted here... please http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior was not the "indirect" call of the function.
In blackjack.py the function is used with `numpy` ints, like this

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

cmp(np.array([10]), np.array([19]))

> array([ True], dtype=bool)

Answer (score -1):

Python will automatically convert the boolean results of `(a > b)` to an integer `1` and `(a < b)` to `0` if indeed `a` is greater because of the minus sign. So in this case, it's equivalent to calculating `1 - 0`, which should return `1`. There is likely some more code that's turning that into a `True`, but this function should just return `1`, `0`, or `-1`.

Comment: the OP knows what it `should just return` and wants to debug why it does not do that

Answer (score -2):

In Python, sorting functions now take a `key`, but in other languages sorting functions require a comparison functions like the one in your question.

The result value should be negative if a < b, zero if a == b, and posititve if a > b.

That is exactly what this function does. Just remember that `False` is evaluated as 0 and `True` as 1.

Comment: `result value should be ...` to achieve what in python?

Comment: @Aprillion Return value  of -1/0/+1 is typical for comparison function used e.g. in C language qsort(), or in Perl where there is a special `<=>` operator for this. Also Python 2 uses such functions (now called old-style) e.g. in `list.sort`, but Python 3 introduced the key parameter (and a convertor `functools.cmp_to_key`). Whoever wrote that function, IMHO this was his goal.

Comment: from the github link: `reward = cmp(score(self.player), score(self.dealer));
 if self.natural and is_natural(self.player) and reward == 1:
reward = 1.5`

Comment: @Aprillion If you are reacting to my comment, what is your question?

Comment: the question in the original post is `Can you explain why?` in my first question I should perhaps asked how this answer is useful in relation to that question... my reaction to your comment `IMHO this was his goal` was an example from the actual code that contradicts your honest opinion and I have no further questions.

Comment: @Aprillion The title is `False - True in Python` and I hope I did answered how it is evaluated and what is the result and where are such functions typically used. Hope it was useful to the author of the question. I did not analyze the context where it was used in the linked github source. That was not part of the question as I understand it.